# Submitting Value of Jquery Button To Server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have a form with several buttons, i want to submit the form to the server using script so i use a function bind to the click events of the buttons. On the server side i want to be able to get the value of the button that was clicked. How can this be achieved?

Using the conventional method to post the form i am able to do a request.getParameter() and get the value of the button that was clicked. I would also like to do a request.getParameter() on the server side and get this parameter or some other more efficient method. Under is what i have:

**jquery**

```
 function submitPage(){

        document.getElementById("citizenRegistration").action="citizen_registration.htm";
        document.getElementById("citizenRegistration").target="_self";    
        document.getElementById("citizenRegistration").method = "POST";
        document.getElementById("citizenRegistration").submit();

    }

     $(document).ready(function(){          

        $('#query').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
                    //need to send the value of the button to server
                    alert($(this).val());
            //alert("hello");
            submitPage();

        });

    });
```

**Jsp**

```
 <li><input id="save" type="submit" name= "user_request" value="Save"/>
    <input id="update" type="submit" name= "user_request" value="Update"/>
    <input id="query" type="submit" name= "user_request" value="Query"/>
 </li>
```

Comment: It can be send by using query string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function submitPage(actionFlag){

     // actionFlag value can be save,update,Query

     document.getElementById("citizenRegistration").action=
                       "citizen_registration.htm?actionFlag="+actionFlag;

     document.getElementById("citizenRegistration").target="_self";       
     document.getElementById("citizenRegistration").method = "POST";
     document.getElementById("citizenRegistration").submit();

}
```

And you can send the button value to the function.

```
    $('#query').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        //need to send the value of the button to server
        var buttonVal = $(this).val();
        alert(buttonVal);
        submitPage();
    });
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: you forgot to pass buttonVal into submitPage() in the click function

Comment: Thanks for your answer and you help also this approach you showed me allows the parameter to be passed via the url i also looked at an approach where i used jquery to create a hidden input element when the button is clicked passing the value and name attribute from the button to the hidden element. This then got posted to the server. Your apporach is also very simple just a minor adjustment to the Controller to accept the parameter rather than requesting it.

Comment: i am having more problems now this can you take a look for me i need some advice here urgently http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15456724/spring-mvc-pages-http-status-400-and-incorrect-urls