# Spring MVC Pages HTTP Status 400 and Incorrect URL's

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, url-routing

I am experiencing some issues with the application. I have a registration form which is post to another page from the controller 
this page displays the results of the query from the registration form. On the results page i select a record and it returns me with the 
data to the registration page. The user should be able to update the record once its returned or execute a query again.

The problems i am having is when the user is on the registration form and executes a query they are posted to the results page
the results page is displayed however the url does not change. The registration url is `http://localhost:8084/crimeTrack/citizen_registration.htm`
when posted to the results page by clicking the query button the url is still `http://localhost:8084/crimeTrack/citizen_registration.htm`
when a record is clicked/selected on the results page (which has several records) the user is posted back to the registration page with the 
selected record and it is displayed for the user to now execute an update or a query again, the url is `http://localhost:8084/crimeTrack/getCitizen/1985121244.htm`
and the user is now on the registration page.

If i click query/update again i am getting an **HTTP 400 error** and the url is reading `http://localhost:8084/crimeTrack/getCitizen/citizen_registration.htm/`
and this is not a valid URL mapping in the Controller. I think the url should be  `http://localhost:8084/crimeTrack/citizen_registration.htm` when the registration page is 
requested. I am not sure when the POST from the results page takes the user back to the registration page is the url should be  `http://localhost:8084/crimeTrack/getCitizen/1985121244.htm`
the attached number is the citizen number. Under is my code i am not sure if i am doing these calls correctly and i would like an explanation for the results i am getting as well as 
a solution to the issues experienced;

Pages are submitted using **jquery**:

This is an example for the registration page and all other pages follow the same pattern

**JScript**

```
function submitPage(){   

    document.getElementById("citizenRegistration").action="citizen_registration.htm";
    //document.getElementById("citizenRegistration").target="_self";    
    document.getElementById("citizenRegistration").method = "POST";
    document.getElementById("citizenRegistration").submit();

}
```

**citizen_registration.jsp**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN">
<html lang="en">

    <head>  


    <title>Citizen Registration</title>

</head> 
    <body>              
            <div id="tab1" class="divGroup">
                <form:form id="citizenRegistration" name ="citizenRegistration" commandName="citizens">
                    ........................
                        <div class="buttons">   
                            <ol>
                                <li><input class="button" id="save" type="submit" name= "user_request" value="Save"/>
                                    <input class="button" id="update" type="submit" name= "user_request" value="Update"/>
                                    <input class="button" id="query" type="submit" name= "user_request" value="Query"/>
                                </li>       

                </form:form>
            </div>          
    </body>
</html>
```

**citizenList.jsp**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

   <script type="text/javascript">

   function submitPage(socialSecurityNumber){    

        document.getElementById("citizenList").action="getCitizen/1985121244.htm";//harded coded for testing
        //document.getElementById("citizenList").target="_self";    
        document.getElementById("citizenList").method = "POST";
        document.getElementById("citizenList").submit();

    }

 function GetCitizenTypeDescription(citizenTypeId){                 
        $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:'getCitizenTypeDescription.htm',
        data:{citizenTypeId:citizenTypeId},
        dataType: 'text',       

        success: function (data) {      
        $('.citizenTypeId').each(function(i){               
                if($(this).val() === citizenTypeId){
                    //finds parent div
                    var parent = $(this).parent();
                    //search for child element wit class name citizenTypeDesc
                    var thisCitizenTypeDesc = parent.children('.citizenTypeDesc');                  
                    thisCitizenTypeDesc.text(data);
                }  
        });
    }


    });

}    
    <title>Citizen Search Results</title>

</head>
<body>
<form:form id="citizenList" name ="citizenList">
<div id ="content">
<c:forEach items="${citizens}" var="citizen">
<div id="table">    
    <div>
        <p><canvas class="canvas" height="240" width="320"></canvas>
    </div>
        <label class="citizenTypeDesc"></label></br>

        <a class="socialSecurityNumber" href="${citizen.socialSecurityNumber}">${citizen.fName}  ${citizen.lName}</a> 
        <input type="hidden" id="photo" value="${citizen.photo}" class="photos"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="socialSecurityNumber" value="${citizen.socialSecurityNumber}" />
        <input type="hidden" class="citizenTypeId" value="${citizen.citizenTypeId}"/>

</div>
</c:forEach>
</div>
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

**CitizenRegistrationController.java**

```
@Controller
public class CitizenRegistrationController {


    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass()); 

    @Autowired
    private CitizenTypeManager citizenTypeManager;
    ............

    Map<String, Object> myCitizenType    = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    .......

    @InitBinder("citizens") 
    protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder){        

        //removes white spaces 
        binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new StringTrimmerEditor(true));

        //formats date 
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        //By passing true this will convert empty strings to null
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true));
        dateFormat.setLenient(false);

      //binder.setValidator(new OfficerRegistrationValidation());
      binder.setValidator(citizenRegistrationValidation);

      binder.registerCustomEditor(Integer.class,new CustomIntEditor());


    }

    @RequestMapping(value="citizen_registration.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView loadPage(@ModelAttribute Citizens citizen, 
                                 BindingResult result,
                                 ModelMap m,
                                 Model model,
                                 HttpServletRequest request,
                                 HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {



        try{
             logger.debug("In Http method for CitizenRegistrationController");       

             myCitizenType.put("citizenTypeList",       this.citizenTypeManager.getCitizenType());
             myGender.put("genderList",                 this.genderManager.getGenderList());             
             ......



            return new ModelAndView("citizen_registration");

        }catch(Exception e){

            logger.error("Exception in CitizenRegistrationController - ModelAndView loadPage "+e);
            request.setAttribute("error",e.getMessage());
            return new ModelAndView("error_page");  

        }   

    }

    @RequestMapping(value="citizen_registration.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(@Valid @ModelAttribute Citizens citizen, 
                                        BindingResult result,
                                        ModelMap m,
                                        Model model,
                                        @RequestParam(value="user_request") String user_request) throws Exception {


        try{
             logger.debug("In Http method for CitizenRegistrationController - Punishment Registration");
             logger.debug("User Request Is " + user_request);


                 if(result.hasErrors()){

                     logger.debug("Has Errors");
                    return new ModelAndView("citizen_registration");
                 }else{

                     //check if its a save of an update

                     if(user_request.equals("Save")){

                         citizenManager.RegisterCitizen(citizen);   
                         model.addAttribute("icon","ui-icon ui-icon-circle-check");
                         model.addAttribute("results","Record Was Saved");
                         return new ModelAndView("citizen_registration");

                     }else if (user_request.equals("Query")){
                         logger.debug("about to preform query");
                         //citizenManager.getListOfCitizens(citizen);
                         if(citizenManager.getListOfCitizens(citizen).isEmpty()){

                             model.addAttribute("icon","ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close");
                             model.addAttribute("results","Notice: Query Caused No Records To Be Retrived!");                            


                         }else{
                             model.addAttribute("citizens",citizenManager.getListOfCitizens(citizen));
                             return new ModelAndView("citizenList"); 


                         }                      

                     }else if (user_request.equals("Update")){
                         logger.info("About to do update");

                         citizenManager.UpdateCitizen(citizen);

                         return new ModelAndView("citizen_registration");                        
                     }                  
                 }

                     logger.debug("Has No Errors");     

            return new ModelAndView("citizen_registration");

        }catch(Exception e){

            logger.error("Exception in CitizenRegistrationController - ModelAndView loadPage "+e);
            //request.setAttribute("error",e.getMessage());

             return new ModelAndView("citizen_registration");

        }

    }

         @RequestMapping(value="getCitizen/{socialSecurityNumber}.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
         public ModelAndView getCitizen(@PathVariable Integer socialSecurityNumber,@ModelAttribute Citizens citizen, 
                                        BindingResult result,ModelMap m,Model model,HttpServletRequest request,  
                                        HttpServletResponse response) {

             try {
                 model.addAttribute("citizens",citizenManager.getCitizen(socialSecurityNumber));
                 //model.addAttribute("citizens",citizenManager.getCitizen(socialSecurityNumber));
            } catch (Exception e) {

                logger.error("Exception in CitizenRegistrationController - ModelAndView getCitizen "+e);
            }

            return new ModelAndView("citizen_registration");     

         }


     @RequestMapping(value="getCitizenTypeDescription.htm", method=RequestMethod.GET)
     public @ResponseBody String citizenTypeDescription(@RequestParam Integer citizenTypeId)throws Exception{

        String data = "No Data Found";

         try{

            data = citizenTypeManager.getCitizenTypeDescription(citizenTypeId);

         }catch(Exception e){
             data = e.getMessage();          
             logger.error("Exception In getCitizenTypeDescription.htm error : " + e);
         }

         return data;    

     }   
//setter methods    
    /**
     * @param citizenTypeManager the citizenTypeManager to set
     */
    public void setCitizenTypeManager(CitizenTypeManager citizenTypeManager) {
        this.citizenTypeManager = citizenTypeManager;
    }
    ................................

}
```

**Edit**

I tried using  `return new ModelAndView("redirect:/citizenList.htm");` in the controller when the user clicks query however i am getting `404 Not Found - http://localhost:8084/crimeTrack/citizenList.htm"`

**Servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-context-3.0.xsd">




<!-- __________________________________________________________________________________________________ -->    

     <!-- Supports annotations and allows the use of @Controller, @Required, @RequestMapping -->
    <context:annotation-config/>    

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.crimetrack.business"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.crimetrack.jdbc"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.crimetrack.service"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.crimetrack.web" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />  

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/public-resources/"/>

 <!-- __________________________________________________________________________________________________ -->    

    <!-- Forwards requests to the "/" resource to the "login" view -->  
    <mvc:view-controller path="/login" view-name="login"/>

    <!-- Forwards requests to the "/" resource to the "officer_registration" view -->  
    <mvc:view-controller path="/officer_registration" view-name="officer_registration"/>


    <!-- Forwards requests to the "/" resource to the "citizenList" view -->  
    <mvc:view-controller path="/citizenList" view-name="citizenList"/>


    <!-- Forwards requests to the "/" resource to the "citizen_registration" view --> 
    <mvc:view-controller path="/citizen_registration" view-name="citizen_registration"/>

<!-- __________________________________________________________________________________________________ -->    

    <!--  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/> --> 

    <!--  Is used to process method level annotations -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>    
<!-- __________________________________________________________________________________________________ -->    

    <!-- <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter"/>  --> 

     <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
            <property name="basename" value="messages"/>
     </bean>


     <bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />
<!-- __________________________________________________________________________________________________ --> 


      <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>        
      </bean>



</beans>
```

Comment: `@PathVariable` concept can be the solution for your requirement

Comment: Try to modify your request mapping like this ...... `@RequestMapping(value="getCitizen.htm/{socialSecurityNumber}", method = RequestMethod.POST)`

Comment: i am getting the getCitizen url mapping to work as well as the PathVariable the issue is when i am on the registration page i execute a query and i am taken to a results list page when i am on that page i the click on on of the results. It then takes me back to the registration page so i now have a record being displayed to me. Now here is where the problem is if i click update or query i am getting Http 404 error http://localhost:8084/crimeTrack/getCitizen/citizen_registration.htm which is an incorrect url idk how getCitizen gets appended to the citizen_registration

Comment: and nothing in the controller is mapped or found with that url localhost:8084/crimeTrack/getCitizen/citizen_registration.htm. The controller should look for citizen_registration mapping and preform either the query redirecting the user to the results list page or update the record and return the user to the same page. Also redirect is not working for any jsp pages inside the jsp folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) change the input type to button instead of submit and add an onclick event that will call your submitPage function passing in the action to call

```
<input class="button" id="save" type="button" name="user_request" value="Save"     onclick="submitPage('citizen_registration.htm');"/>
<input class="button" id="update" type="button" name="user_request" value="Update" onclick="submitPage('citizen_registration.htm');"/>
<input class="button" id="query" type="button" name="user_request" value="Query" onclick="submitPage('citizen_list.htm');"/>
```

2) change your submitPage function to set the action based on which button was clicked

```
function submitPage(action){   
    document.getElementById("citizenRegistration").action = action;
    document.getElementById("citizenRegistration").method = "POST";
    document.getElementById("citizenRegistration").submit();
}
```

3) have 2 controller methods, one mapped to save/update, the other mapped to list

```
@RequestMapping(value="citizen_list.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView getCitizenList(@Valid @ModelAttribute Citizens citizen, BindingResult result, ModelMap m, Model model, @RequestParam(value="user_request") String user_request) throws Exception {

   try{
        logger.debug("about to preform query");
        //citizenManager.getListOfCitizens(citizen);
        if(citizenManager.getListOfCitizens(citizen).isEmpty()){
             model.addAttribute("icon","ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close");
             model.addAttribute("results","Notice: Query Caused No Records To Be Retrived!");                            
        }else{
             model.addAttribute("citizens",citizenManager.getListOfCitizens(citizen));
             return new ModelAndView("citizenList"); 
        } 
    }catch(Exception e){
        logger.error("Exception in CitizenRegistrationController - ModelAndView loadPage "+e);
        //request.setAttribute("error",e.getMessage());
         return new ModelAndView("citizen_registration");
    }
}

@RequestMapping(value="citizen_registration.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView handleRequest(@Valid @ModelAttribute Citizens citizen,  BindingResult result, ModelMap m, Model model, @RequestParam(value="user_request") String user_request) throws Exception {

    try{
         logger.debug("In Http method for CitizenRegistrationController - Punishment Registration");
         logger.debug("User Request Is " + user_request);

         if(result.hasErrors()){
            logger.debug("Has Errors");
            return new ModelAndView("citizen_registration");
         }else{
             //check if its a save of an update
             if(user_request.equals("Save")){
                 citizenManager.RegisterCitizen(citizen);   
                 model.addAttribute("icon","ui-icon ui-icon-circle-check");
                 model.addAttribute("results","Record Was Saved");
                 return new ModelAndView("citizen_registration");
             } else if (user_request.equals("Update")){
                 logger.info("About to do update");
                 citizenManager.UpdateCitizen(citizen);
                 return new ModelAndView("citizen_registration");                        
             }                  
         }

        logger.debug("Has No Errors");     
        return new ModelAndView("citizen_registration");

    }catch(Exception e){
        logger.error("Exception in CitizenRegistrationController - ModelAndView loadPage "+e);
        //request.setAttribute("error",e.getMessage());
         return new ModelAndView("citizen_registration");
    }
}
```

Comment: i am submitting he page using jscript i dont think there is any need to include the action in the form tag?

Comment: the issue i am having is when i am on the registration form and i click query i am taken to the citizenList.htm and that fine i dont use a redirect to get to this page i do a  return new ModelAndView("citizenList"); and the page is returned ok with the results however the url doesn't change it stays as http://localhost:8084/crimeTrack/citizen_registration.htm.

Comment: Ah, I see, you're returning new ModelAndView("citizenList") and you expect to see the URL change to something like localhost:8084/crimeTrack/citizenList.htm.  Is that correct?  If that's the case you need a separate controller method to retrieve the citizenList that's mapped to the URL you'd like to see. Right now you have everything in the handleRequest method which is mapped to citizen_registration.htm.  You want something like @RequestMapping("/citizenList.htm") public ModelAndView getCitizenList() ...

Comment: yes that's correct however i am preforming the operation on the same form for i.e on the registration form i have a query button and the page is already mapped to the citizen_registration request mapping. The other page functions like save and update are all happening in the citizen_registration request mapping. The difference is the query function takes you to another view but the save and update doesn't.

Comment: if i create a new mapping like you said for citizenList how can i get the query button to called that mapping if the entire registration view is mapped to the citizen_registration request mapping. Is there a way to send the user to another mapping form within the citizen mapping? What i am really doing is looking at the button value to preform save, update and query

Comment: You need to change the form's action based on which button was clicked. If the query button is clicked you need to set the form action to citizen_list.htm before posting it so the request is routed to your new citizenList controller method. `document.getElementById("citizenRegistration").action="citizen_list.htm";`

Comment: ok great so would you say its feasible to hard code the url mapping on the buttons then use java script to get this value and set it as the form action? Is this the best way whats the most feasible way to do this. is it safe to say you have one view mapped to several urls? Does that comply with MVC? I am seeing a brighter picture here now thou. Maybe you can modify your answer so i can accept it as well

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example of setting the action based on which button was clicked. The basic steps are 1) change the submit buttons to a regular buttons and add an onclick function that will call submitPage passing in what action to call, 2) update the submitPage function to specify the action before posting, 3) update the controller to have 2 methods, one for save/update that's mapped to citizen_registration.htm and another for query that's mapped to citizen_list.htm.

Comment: great thanks alot i think this happen due to mu inexperience in usin spring. Also i want to askdo i still need to use redirect in the controller?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do a redirect, the javascript will post to the correct controller method which will return the correct ModelAndView. Since you've accepted the answer, are you going to award the bounty?

Comment: hey i tried to accept the bounty and it told me i needed to wait 18 hours so i will come back and accept it

Comment: Can you tell me one more thing i have done all this and it works fine however when i am on the registration screen http://localhost:8084/crimeTrack/citizen_registration.htm and i click query i am taken to the results list http://localhost:8084/crimeTrack/citizenList.htm all fine and well then when i click on a record it takes me back to the registration page with the record http://localhost:8084/crimeTrack/getCitizen/1985010122.htm all fine and well

Comment: However this is where the problem is if i click query again with a record on the screen it is suppose to take me to the citizenList url mapping again however the url is now reading http://localhost:8084/crimeTrack/getCitizen/citizenList.htm and HTTP 400 status can you tell me why this is happening

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26502/discussion-between-clav-and-dev-darin)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are using relative paths here when you say `action="citizen_registration.htm"`.

Change it to

```
document.getElementById("citizenRegistration").action="/crimeTrack/citizen_registration.htm";
```

or

```
document.getElementById("citizenRegistration").action="../citizen_registration.htm";
```

Comment: This did not solve the problem in any way if the form is submitted without js the problem is still there